# passing upload URL for flow-init's target from controller in angularjs + flow.js dynamically

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, angularjs-directive, angular-file-upload

I want to pass dynamic url to flow-init's target property. the URL was generated at runtime.

If I assign a scope object which contains the properties for flow-ini. Then it return parse error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue:

`flow-init="{target: baseUrl + 'some_url_location/another_url_location/{{entityID}}/'}"`

and changed to

`flow-init="{target: baseUrl + 'some_url_location/another_url_location/' + entityID + '/'}"`

where entityID is $scope.entityID in my js controller. This $scope.entityID is taken from the current URL.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller create a function to the scope taking the $flow variable and setting it's target to your dynamic url, also use the $flow.upload function here:

```
$scope.submitFlow =  function($flow) {
    $flow.opts.target = '/user/'+ $scope.user.id +'/submit-file';
    $flow.upload();
  };
```

Then in your html, in the flow-init div, set the flow-files-submitted to our function:

```
<div flow-init
         flow-files-submitted="submitFlow($flow)"
         flow-file-success="$file.msg = $message">
```